# How I can change format of a picture?

Tags: windows-7, format, pictures

I have windows 7 and I really can not find how change picture format without photoshop! Have windows 7 any standard program to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What format do you need?  Windows Paint supports BMP, JPG, GIF and PNG.

Comment: I'm a real fool. I forgot about Windows Paint! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most image editors or image viewers let you save the picture you have opened in them in a different format.  This is the easiest way to "convert" to a different format most of the time.

Examples include Irfanview (lightweight), GIMP, Ulead's iPhoto Plus!, and MS Paint.
Irfanview (with plugins) is my personal favorite for this task.  There's many others.

You can install [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) to use the `convert` command to convert (or do many things such as superimpose text or resize) large number of images from a command-line script.